# How to use sbt-jslint in Play Framework 2.0.x scala?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'd like to integrate [sbt-jslint](https://github.com/philcali/sbt-jslint) into an existing Play Framework 2.0.x project using Scala.

Has anyone done this before? What are the configuration steps that will integrate jslint into the `play test` run, and present the failures as an integrated part of the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(this answer via @jzsfkzm, who kindly posted an [excellent response](https://github.com/philcali/sbt-jslint/issues/5#issuecomment-9466432) to the [github issue](https://github.com/philcali/sbt-jslint/issues/5), but did not choose to repost his answer here.)*

On our projects the plugin is added in the *plugins.sbt* and configured in the *Build.scala*. Examples below.

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.philcali" % "sbt-jslint" % "0.1.3")
```

**project/Build.scala**

```
import sbtjslint.Plugin._
import sbtjslint.Plugin.LintKeys._

...

val localSettings = lintSettings ++ inConfig(Compile)(Seq(
    // jslint
    sourceDirectory in jslint <<= (baseDirectory)(_ / "public" / "javascripts"),
    excludeFilter in jslint := "generated" || "lib",
    flags in jslint := Seq("sloppy", "continue", "vars", "nomen")
))

def playProject = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
    localSettings : _*
)
```

The task we use to run jslint is `play jslint`, it'll check your code and create an xml file, *target/jslint/results.xml* for further usage. You can use it in the Jenkins Violations plugin for example.